# Dynamic CRM 2016 on premises theme customization

Tags: javascript, css, dynamics-crm

There are very limited option in dynamic crm theme customization. See image

[image: CRM Default Theme]

Can we have some other option to customization?

I want to change background color, font-style, padding, margin etc.

Thanks

J.T.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only supported option.  Past that you can create web-resources with jscript to inject styles into your pages at load time.  [This article](https://snataw.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/prettify-entity-form-in-crm-2013/) contains a nice walkthrough of how the process works including code.

I have done this on several systems with varying levels of style changes and the results have been good.

Edit:
As J notes in his comment, this may not work with CRM 2015 SP 1 and CRM 2016 exactly as described in the article because of the new rendering engine.

Comment: I have seen this article and tried but not working in CRM 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You have only this option, there is no more option then that.

If you want change you can change by create some code and change the code of the crm but this is not supported and I recommended not go by this way because if you are not sure what you are doing you can broke the system.